# Azure AD and Azure B2C for users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Our organization has a on premise Active directory.For few of our applications we want to implement authentication mechanism using Azure AD. Following is the requirement:

1) Organization users will be authenticated by Azure AD

2) External users will be authenticated by Azure AD B2C

3) Whenever an external user is trying to access the application, application will redirect the user to B2C login page.

Can anyone help me with steps for the solution?

Also, is there any issues to implement the security mechanism using Azure AD and B2C if the application resides in AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case B2C custom policies are perfect fit. you can get start on custom policies from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom

> 1) Organization users will be authenticated by Azure AD

You can integrate this in custom policies. Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom

> 2) External users will be authenticated by Azure AD B2C

Once you add custom policies those will allow you to login users from external network/ social IDPs

> 3) Whenever an external user is trying to access the application,
>   application will redirect the user to B2C login page.

It's all about configuration. If you configure properly it will take you to B2C login page. If you stuck while integrating drop comment here.

> Also, is there any issues to implement the security mechanism using
>   Azure AD and B2C if the application resides in AWS?

I don't think you will face challenges. Cloud redirects will happen and works fine with B2C too.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now with a latest feature supported by Azure, I can map my existing Azure AD to B2C as an identity provider.Now I have one more challenge. I have 4 B2C  tenants for different applications which is used by 4 different set of external users and the existing internal users from Azure AD. I have setup 4 Azure AD for 4 B2C tenants. This became a challenge for  syncing users between different Azure ADs. Can I map a single Azure AD as identity provider for 4 different B2C tenant? Could you please help with the implementation steps?

Comment: Could anyone suggest if I can use same Azure AD for muliple B2C tenants?

Comment: You can use. This is possible. All you need to do is, create multiple technical profiles and RP xml files. But you will get a challenge like syncing users. if you use 4 Azure B2C tenants, this mean you are tryinig to replicate and allowing your single AD users into 4 different B2C tenants. if your business requirement is like that, then you can go for it.

Answer (score 1):

For a specific sample of how to implement these custom policies, see [Woodgrove Groceries demo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-external-identities-woodgrove-demo), which enables users to sign in with either:

1. An "individual customer" account (i.e. a local account that is managed by Azure AD B2C or a Google or Microsoft account that is federated with it); or
2. A "business customer" account (i.e. an Azure AD account that is federated with Azure AD B2C); or
3. A "partner" account that is a direct federation between the end-user application and Azure AD (where Azure AD B2C doesn't act as an intermediate federation).